# Count number of a specific conditional event for unique id in a rolling window over time with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have the first DataFrame and I would like to get the second one with the new column counter.

Logic: using a rolling window (example df.rolling('1min').agg(lambda ...)),
for each unique id in the window, the column "counter" is 1 if "full" or "partial" is found at least one time. Once it is found for the first time, we write 1 and we don't need to check further in the window.

For example, below, the id '2' had two times the 'partial event' within the same window, counter is therefore 0.

Counter is always 0 or 1.

Note that there are other events other than 'full' and 'partial' in the column event which we should ignore.

```
timestamp                id  event    
2021-10-26 10:00:00.000  1   full     
2021-10-26 10:00:01.000  2   partial  
2021-10-26 10:00:03.090  3   full     
2021-10-26 10:00:05.090  2   partial  
2021-10-26 10:00:05.590  4   event_z
2021-10-26 10:00:05.690  4   event_z
2021-10-26 10:00:05.790  4   event_b


timestamp                id  event    counter
2021-10-26 10:00:00.000  1   full     1
2021-10-26 10:00:01.000  2   partial  1
2021-10-26 10:00:03.090  3   full     1
2021-10-26 10:00:05.090  2   partial  0
2021-10-26 10:00:05.090  4   event_z  0
2021-10-26 10:00:05.090  4   event_z  0
2021-10-26 10:00:05.090  4   event_b  0

df['counter'].rolling('1min').agg(lambda ... ?)
```

I am having hard time to write a complicate formula as lambda function, maybe better to split the problem in two and create intermediate columns ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
m = df['event'].isin(['full','partial'])
df.loc[m, 'new'] = pd.factorize(df.loc[m, 'event'])[0]

def f(x):
    a = x.duplicated() & x.notna()
    return ~a.any()
df = df.groupby('id')['new'].rolling('1min').apply(f).fillna(0).reset_index(level=0).sort_index()
print (df)
                         id  new
timestamp                       
2021-10-26 10:00:00.000   1  1.0
2021-10-26 10:00:01.000   2  1.0
2021-10-26 10:00:03.090   3  1.0
2021-10-26 10:00:05.090   2  0.0
2021-10-26 10:00:05.590   4  0.0
2021-10-26 10:00:05.690   4  0.0
2021-10-26 10:00:05.790   4  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the proposition jezrael.
I think this might not work as there are as well other types of event other than 'partial' and 'full'. Am I right ?

Comment: @LaGabriella - hmmm, then it means not understand your function, can you add more rows to sample data for explain why my solution failed?

Comment: @LaGabriella - in another words - need test if duplciates only `full` or `partial` then set 0 else 1 ?

Comment: I just completed my question. My bad, it was not clearly specified.
the column "counter" is 1 if  "full" or "partial" is found at least one time. Once it is found for the first time, we write 1 and we don't need to check further in the window.

Comment: thank you again ! I will try this out. regarding the last table, two last values for id2 should be 0 and not 1 . maybe a typo ?

Comment: @LaGabriella - Need soemthing more complicated, main problem is `.agg` return aggregated values, so thinking how changed solution.

Comment: @LaGabriella - Min problem is `forget` - like need `Once it is found for the first time, we write 1 and we don't need to check further in the window.`

Comment: how about the use of duplicated(keep='last') ? it seems to mark the first duplicate as true while the rest is false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238530/discussion-between-lagabriella-and-jezrael).

Comment: @LaGabriella - Problem is values are aggregated, you need working no aggragtion

Comment: @LaGabriella - Can you test? But still not sure if working in real data, because forget part is not implemented.

Comment: Hi, It didn't work. Still trying to figure this out!

Comment: @LaGabriella Can you change data for see how solution failed?

Comment: @LaGabriella - One idea - is possible say - set `1` only if first `id` value and `event` is ` 'full' or 'partial'` else set `0`?